# PHP: sum parts of a string without explode()

Tags: php, regex, sum, explode

I have some strings in this format `15-37;10-38;5-39;`, `5-XXS;45-XS;`.

Before the `-` is the quantity, after the `-` is the size. `;` indicates the start of a new pair.

Without having to `explode()` the string two times, is there a way I can add all the quantities ?

For example, the total quantities for `15-37;10-38;5-39;` will be 30.

Thank you.

Comment: Why the arbitrary exclusion of using explode()?

Comment: [Getting creative...](https://eval.in/172621) but really, just explode :)

Comment: This is inside a loop, I have about 50 rows so I thought it will be slow to add 2 explodes for each loop plus all the other operations I perform. I just wanted to know if there is a way of doing it without explode(), but if there is none, I'll use it.

Comment: @C.Ovidiu exploding two times is certainly faster than using regex :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with `preg_match()`

```
$str ='15-37;10-38;5-39;';
preg_match_all('/(?P<digit>\d+)-/', $str, $matches);
```

or

```
preg_match_all('/(\d+)-/', $str, $matches);
echo array_sum($matches[0]); //30
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the following code:

```
$helper = "15-37;10-38;5-39;";
$sum=0;
for($i=0; $i<$helper.length; $i++){

    if($helper[$i]=="-"){   

        while($helper[$i]!=";")
        $i++;
    }
    else
    {
    if($helper[$i]!=";"){
        $aux="";
        while($helper[$i]!="-" && $helper[$i]!=";"){

            $aux = $aux.$helper[$i];
            //echo $helper[$i]." ";
            $k++;
            $i++;

        }
        $i--;
        echo (int)$aux."<br>";
        $sum = $sum + intval($aux);

    }
    }


}

echo $sum;
```

You can test it here: http://writecodeonline.com/php/
The last outputed number is the sum.

Hope it helps!